# What are the implications of having a Youth Mobility visa denied?

Tags: visas, germany, visa-refusals, spouses

My wife, who is a Canadian citizen, lives currently in Canada. I live in Germany under a working visa. I emailed the German consulate in Toronto, asking if I could be financing my wife's Youth Mobility visa, but they came back with an answer that she couldn't apply for it at all, and we should apply for a family reunion visa instead (which is not possible due to the fact that I haven't been a resident for 2 years here yet).

Considering these facts, I'm unsure how to proceed. I could provide my wife with the funds to apply for the Youth Mobility visa so we can reunite, and then apply for family reunion when the time is due (around the end of this year), but now we fear rejection.

In the application form of the Youth Mobility visa, there are sections asking for spouse information, where she needs to input my name, address etc. As well as this checkbox:

> I intend to stay no longer than twelve months in the Federal territory and apply for a visa that covers the whole duration of my stay.

Which in our case isn't true as she intends to stay longer than 12 months. I asked at the local foreigner's office and they said they would provide the extension without a problem, but they have given me false information in the past, so I don't just want to take their word for it.

---

So to the question: if my wife applies for this visa and happens to get rejected/denied, what kind of implications will this have for us in the future? We want to do the family reunion smoothly, but this is kind of complicating things. We also hate the distance between us very much and would like to get rid of it ASAP.

Assuming she gets denied for the Youth Mobility Visa, what would happen the next time she gets on a plane, comes to Germany (she doesn't need a tourist visa) and speaks to the border officer? Will they turn her back because she has been denied? How can she say "hey, I'm here to actually apply for family reunion visa"?

I would highly appreciate your advice on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: If you do not wish your questions up any more, I'd suggest that you delete them outright instead of just removing the content... the way they are now, it isn't useful for anybody.

Comment: It is not allowed to deface questions. When you signed up you agreed to leave your posted content online forever.

Comment: If you want to disengage your questions from your account you need to follow the method in this Q and A: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-4-0/96746#96746

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Youth Mobility visa is for young people who want to travel abroad for a short period of time. The intention is for them to experience other countries temporarily. It explicitly says that the period limit is one year.

Your wife's intention is very different, She want to join you in Germany and live there on a permanent basis. The Youth Mobility visa is not appropriate. This is clearly shown by the question you mention, which your wife us unable truthfully to say yes to. She intends to stay longer than a year. It's irrelevant whether the visa could be extended or not.

If your wife does not mark the checkbox she will not be given a Youth Mobility visa. If she does, then she will be suspected, with good reason, of having lied on her form. The repercussions of the latter will be much worse than being denied a visa.

Questions about how to have your wife join you permanently in Germany belong on [our Expatriates site](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have asked on the other site for the new problem that I wasn't aware of. I don't know why this has to be so complicated, but sadly it is.

Comment: @Aborted The fourth paragraph is incorrect. See [section 41](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/__41.html) of the [Aufenthaltsverordnung](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthv/index.html).

Comment: @phoog This is excellent!!!! THANK YOU! Can you post this in the other question as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Removed the doubtful paragraph